# Custom Regular expression in model property ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement a regular expression validation that allows `a-z A-z  0-9` and some special characters  `_  -  . @  &`

But should restrict

```
\ / " : ; * ? " < > { } [ ] ( ) | ! ' % ^
```

tried this pattern but doesn't work.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
[RegularExpression("^[-a-zA-Z0-9_-@]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid characters!")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Could you please suggest?

Comment: why have you added `-` two times?

Comment: Nope.it is a hyphen and an underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex `hyphen` has a special meaning in Character class that is used to define the range. It should be escaped or put it in the beginning or ending of the set.

Try

```
[-\w.@&]
```

Here `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

To validate the whole string use `^` and `$` to match start and end of the string respectively.

To avoid blank string try `+` instead of `*` like `^[-\w.@&]+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9-.@&]*$/
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mQ2yJ7/1)**

If you want to escape hyphen as starting character:

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-.@&]*$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mQ2yJ7/2)**

If you want to restrict it from start and end both then try this:

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-.@&]*+(?<!-)$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mQ2yJ7/4)**

Comment: `hyphen` should be escaped or in the beginning or ending in the set.